# How to draw below Star Pattern in Shell Script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to create below pattern design in Shell script, i have written below codes for the same but i am not getting expected results. can someone help on this?

Desired output-->

```
      *
     **
    ***
   ****
  *****
```

```sh
#! /bin/sh                                                                            
                                                                                      
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))                                                                
  do                                                                                  
    for ((j=1; j<=5; j++))                                                            

       do                                                                             
             if [ $j > 6-$i ]                                                         
                then                                                                  
                echo -n "* "                                                          
             elif [ $j == 6-$i ]                                                      
              then                                                                    
               echo -n "* "                                                           
             else                                                                     
                echo -n "  "                                                          
              fi                                                                      

    done                                                                              
  echo                                                                                
done
```

Current output-->

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use another loop to print the pre-pending spaces.

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++));             # Loop to create 5 lines of text
do 
  for((k=1;k<=(5-i);k++));        # Loop to padd prepending spaces
  do 
    printf "%s" " ";
  done;
  for ((j=1;j<=i;j++));           # Loop to create asterix
  do 
    printf "%s" "*";
  done;
  printf "\n";                    # Print the carriage return
done
```

Comment: Thank you for valuable input, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

to make the minimum number of changes to your code to get it working;  you need to do number comparison, and number addition in order to get your check statements to work:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)) ; do 
    for ((j=1; j<=5; j++)) ; do
     if [ $j -ge $((6-$i)) ] ; then                                                                  
        echo -n "* "
     else
        echo -n "  "
      fi                                                                  
    done                                                                              
  echo                                                                                
done
```

new output:

```
        * 
      * * 
    * * * 
  * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Comment: line 3 can be written: `if ((j >= 6 - i)); then` -- bash's arithmetic expressions can be quite readably C-like

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need so much arithmetic, you can use printf to add the padding:

```sh
n=5
line=''
char='*'

for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
  line+=$char
  printf "%*s\n" $n "$line"
done
```

If you want the triangle leaning the other way:

```sh
  printf "%-*s\n" $n "$line"
```